# Unable to output buffer

Tags: linux, bash, go

I am trying to run `nikto -h {url}` on kali. My `nikto -h` command works fine, but when I add an URL, nothing is output.

I am not sure if it is the process or something else.

How can I see the output directly rather than buffering and displaying it?

```
package main

import (
        "bytes"
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "os/exec"
//      "strings"
)

func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("nikto","-h","google.com")
//      cmd.Stdin = strings.NewReader("some input")
        var out bytes.Buffer
        cmd.Stdout = &out
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```

Comment: `cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout` will route the command output directly to the tty executing your program.

Answer (score 0):

As @Adrian suggested in the comments, using os.Stdout works

```
package main

import (
        "log"
        "os"
        "os/exec"
)

func main() {
        cmd := exec.Command("ls", "-l")
        cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
        err := cmd.Run()
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
        }
}
```